# Multidimensional Arrays. An algorithm for solving

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon!

I need to implement the following algorithm. If the element of the matrix M x N = 0, then all the elements of the rows and columns to assign 0.

Here is my solution:

```
var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 0, 7, 8],
           [8, 9, 10, 11]];

var vertical, horizontal;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
            vertical = j;
            horizontal = i;
        }
    }
}

for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
    if (k == horizontal) {
        for (var l = 0; l < arr[k].length; l++) {
            arr[k][l] = 0;
        }
    }
}

for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    for (var b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++) {
        if (b == vertical) {
            arr[a][b] = 0;
        }
    }
}

for (var c in arr) {
    document.write(arr[c] + '<br />');
}
```

It seems to me not very reasonable. How can I simplify my code?

Comment: Refactoring requests for working code are offtopic here. [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for such questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the for loops to [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

1. First find all cells with value `0` and store the item reference.
2. Iterate through item list and change values to zero for all columns and rows.

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 0, 8], [8, 9, 10, 11]],
    p = [];

arr.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.forEach(function (b, j) {
        if (b === 0) {
            p.push({ x: i, y: j });
        }
    });
});
p.forEach(function (a) {
    arr[a.x] = arr[a.x].map(function () { return 0; });
    arr.forEach(function (b) { b[a.y] = 0; });
});
document.write('<pre>items: ' + JSON.stringify(p, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>arr: ' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```